# Magento 2 Add a block to a layout programatically?

Tags: magento2, layout, blocks, programmatically

```
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    array $data = []
) {
    parent::__construct($context, $data);
    $block  =  $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template')
        ->setTemplate('MyWidgets_ProductTile::widget/test.phtml');

    $this->getLayout()->addBlock($block, 'popup', 'popup.container');
}
```

**This is my default.xml file**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <move element="header.switchers" destination="footer.panel.container" after="-"/>
    <!-- add new popup container-->
    <referenceContainer name="page.wrapper">
        <container name="popup.container" as="popup_container" label="PopupContainer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="popup-container" before="main.content"/>
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

**I get the following error:**

Failed to filter the template: elements with an ID of "popup" are already defined

Comment: Without testing it, I would recommend changing `popup` to something else.

Comment: It doesn't work, I tried other names but still the same...

Comment: Did you `bin/magento cache:clean` after changing name?

Comment: yes, I did but still nothing